# Replacing Transforms with Absolute Positioning in SVGs

Tags: html, css, svg, vector, css-animations

Given this SVG snippet:

```
<g class="serp" transform="translate(29.000000, 194.000000)">
    <g class="search-results-container" transform="translate(192.000000, 12.000000)">
      <g class="result" transform="translate(0.000000, 220.000000)">
        <rect class="line" fill="#F0F0F0" x="0.621052632" y="73" width="346.378947" height="8" rx="4"></rect>
        <rect class="line" fill="#F0F0F0" x="0.621052632" y="60" width="416.684211" height="8" rx="4"></rect>
        <rect class="line" fill-opacity="0.118829257" fill="#15A085" x="0.621052632" y="31" width="78.3789474" height="8" rx="4"></rect>
        <rect class="line" fill="#8D8D8D" x="0.621052632" y="13" width="181.378947" height="8" rx="4"></rect>
        <rect class="line" fill="#8D8D8D" x="0.621052632" y="0" width="224.378947" height="8" rx="4"></rect>
      </g>
   </g>
</g>
```

How can one replace the transform attributes on `<g>` to actual coordinates? I've been trying to animate elements with CSS Transforms, but I don't want to define absolute transform coordinates in CSS, rather move elements relative to their original position.

Comment: remove the transform and add 220 + 12 + 194 to the y of all the rect elements similarly for the x values (29 + 192)

Comment: This is a small snippet of a very large SVG file exported through Sketch. ANy way to apply these transforms to underlying objects in bulk?

Comment: Sure, write some software in a language of your choice to transform the file.